# Add max and min sliders to buttons using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to add UP and DOWN arrow buttons instead of max and min sliders of the colorbar. On clicking UP arrow button the colorbar range values should increase by one step, On Clicking DOWN arrow the colorbar range values should decrease by one step. Can any one help me how can I Add buttons to the sliders to achieve the below.

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Given below is my code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.colors
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
img_data = np.random.rand(50,50)

c_max = "%1.2f"
c_min = "%0.2f"
img = ax.imshow(img_data, interpolation='nearest')
cb = plt.colorbar(img)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_cmin = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', 0, 50, valfmt=c_max)
s_cmin = Slider(ax_cmin, 'min', 0, 50, valinit=c_min)
def update(val, s=None):
    _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim(0, _cmax)
    plt.draw()
s_cmax.on_changed(update)
s_cmin.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```